# Observation Operator - Data Assimilation

Tags: forecasting, estimation, kalman-filter

In data assimilation, one assumes the existence of a observation operator $\mathcal{H}$ that maps the model-state vector $\bf{x_b}$ to $
\bf{y_b}$ (the model-equivalent of the observations $\bf{y_o}$) according to a reference I'm using to develop a preliminary understanding of DA.

Can someone please elaborate on the precise meaning of:

> model-equivalent of the observations $\bf{y_o}$

and the methods one can use to estimate the operator $\mathcal{H}$.

Answer (score 1):

Think of $\mathbf{H}$ as a matrix operator which allows you to extract the part of the modelled state vector, which is observable. Just to give you a trivial example - assuming your state vector consists of 2D location and two velocity components and what you observe is just 2D location (e.g. obtained from GPS):
$$\mathbf{y_o} = \left( \begin{matrix} 
x_o(t)\\
y_o(t)\\
\end{matrix}
\right)$$
$$
\mathbf{x_b} =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x(t)\\
y(t)\\
v_x(t)\\
v_y(t)
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
$$
\mathbf{H}=\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
To check how $\mathbf{H}$ works, calculate on a sheet of paper the following products: $\mathbf{H x_b}$ and $\mathbf{H^T y_o}$.
To construct a proper $\mathbf{H}$ operator you need to understand both what are you observing and what are you modelling.